# How to read the data from multiple sheets of an excel file?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have an excel which contain approx. 25 spread sheets. One sheet is for data entry and 5 sheets showing the result. On other sheets there are lot of calculations. So to track down the output value of particular cell, to find where it came from i have to go through various sheets to reach at its source and it contain lot of time. is there any method to find path of particular value of cell.

Answer (score 0):

To find out how a cell is related to others, use

```
Tools -> Auditing -> Trace Precedents
Tools -> Auditing -> Trace Dependents
```

A whole bunch of arrows may appear, showing you how that value is derived, or used in other formulas.